# symfony 2 standalone forms datetime validation on 'timestamp' input type

Tags: php, forms, validation, symfony

I'm using the Symfony Form and Validator standalone components in a project. I cannot see how the date_format option is ever going to be used to validate against the input value.

I have the fields rendered as:

```
->add('from_date', 'datetime', array(
      'constraints' => array(
        new Assert\DateTime(),
        new Assert\GreaterThan(array(
          'value'   => time(),
          'message' => 'From: date/time must be in the future'
        ))
      ),
      'required'    => true,
      'label'       => 'From date:',
      'date_widget' => 'single_text',
      'time_widget' => 'choice',
      'input'       => 'timestamp',
      'date_format' => 'dd/MM/yyyy',
      'attr'        => array(
        'class'     => 'textbox', 
        'size'      => 15
      ),
      'mapped'      => false
    ))
```

which correctly displays an input box which correctly validates against the date format (eg 12/12/2013) and two dropdowns for hours and minutes.

However, on submission the datetime validator always fails - seemingly because the

```
const PATTERN = '/^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) ... etc
```

is never altered to handle the timestamp that is correctly created. so, this validation check always fails:

```
if (!preg_match(static::PATTERN, $value, $matches) || 
!checkdate($matches[2], $matches[3], $matches[1])) {
```

because $value is now a timestamp, and not in the format inputted.

im not sure if this is just an issue or missing feature when using the forms standalone, but i can't see a way of that configuration ever being able to validate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the value as a \DateTime object?

```
"value" => new \DateTime("NOW"),
```